# PayPal Express Checkout Integration Response

Tags: paypal

I'm currently having a hard time trying to understand the response of my PayPal EC Integration.

GetExpressCheckoutDetails response is

```
[CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated
```

but in DoExpressCheckout response, the

```
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed
```

I'm confused, does this mean the buyer has been charged and the payment was successful or not? I cannot find answers in PayPal forum and portals either... weeeew

Below is the complete response details:

GetExpressCheckout response:

```
        [TOKEN] => EC-76768931K5394210Y
        [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated
        [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-10-20T07:15:22Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => 2b85ff556730a
        [ACK] => Success
        [VERSION] => 94.0
        [BUILD] => 3926908
        [EMAIL] => testpp_per_1348562981_per@gmail.com
        [PAYERID] => 3PCFRVX65A7Y8
        [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
        [FIRSTNAME] => Test
        [LASTNAME] => Peepee
        [COUNTRYCODE] => US
        [CURRENCYCODE] => PHP
        [AMT] => 895.00
        [ITEMAMT] => 895.00
        [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
        [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
        [TAXAMT] => 0.00
        [INVNUM] => 1231313213213
        [INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
        [SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
        [L_NAME0] => Test Item
        [L_QTY0] => 1
        [L_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
        [L_AMT0] => 895.00
        [L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => PHP
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 895.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 895.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM] => 1231313213213
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Test Item
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 895.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] =>    0.00000
        [PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
```

DoExpressCheckout response:

```
        [TOKEN] => EC-76768931K5394210Y
        [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
        [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-10-20T07:15:27Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => ec7af38c18968
        [ACK] => Success
        [VERSION] => 94.0
        [BUILD] => 3926908
        [INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
        [SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 02800680NT5556907
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2012-10-20T07:15:26Z
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 895.00
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT] => 49.91
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => PHP
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => None
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => K3TTNE7MKRJUN
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
        [PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The payment does not take place until *YOU* call DoExpressCheckout.

In the first step (SetExpressCheckout + redirection to PayPal) the buyer is giving you authorization to charge him.  It's now up to you to actually get his money by calling DoExpressCheckout.

If you call GetExpressCheckoutDetails  **after** DoExpressCheckout,  you should get a payment completed response.

Edit: 
One reason you may want to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails before DoExpresCheckout, is to get the address that the buyer selected, in case it may change the totals, so it's still a valid use case.

Comment: I see, that's why it's confusing. I followed the PayPal Express Checkout Integration Guide (Last updated: August 7, 2012) wherein it's SetExpressCheckout -> GetExpressCheckoutDetails -> DoExpressCheckoutPayment. Alright, I'll just ignore the GetExpressCheckout checkout_status and use the returned data of DoExpressCheckoutPayment for my processing. Thanks! :)

Comment: Correct, we do GetExpressCheckoutDetails before DoExpressCheckout to get the country so that we can decide whether to add VAT TAX..