# Payal "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" - why pass $finalPaymentAmount? (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to get the simplest version of Express Checkout working in PHP.

My shopping basket has a button which sends the user to the script provided by the checkout wizard called `expresscheckout.php`.

On the return URL page, I call `GetShippingDetails($_SESSION['TOKEN'])` to get the shipping details of the user. Seemingly undocumented, I get within the response the key/value `'CHECKOUTSTATUS' => 'PaymentActionNotInitiated'`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986426/paypal-express-checkout-integration-response) explains that to complete the transaction I must call `DoExpressCheckout` which is wrapped by the Paypal-provided PHP function `ConfirmPayment( $FinalPaymentAmt )`.

Why is the `$FinalPaymentAmt` argument required? If I'm correct:

- There are three types of `paymentType`: `Sale`, `Authorisation` and `Order`, the first of which is used in the PHP script `expresscheckout.php`, and which according to [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRelatedAPIOps/) "can be completed immediately". Since payment amount is specified in the call preceding the redirection to Paypal in the script's call to the Paypal provided wrapper:

`CallShortcutExpressCheckout(($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);`

**Questions**:

1. Why does it also have to be specified in `ConfirmPayment( $FinalPaymentAmt )`? What would happen if the values specified for `$paymentAmount` and `$finalPaymentAmount` were different?
2. Is the `$FinalPaymentAmt` only required/used if `$paymentType` is not "Sale"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the checkout wizard, but the general Express Checkout flow consists of 3 API requests.

- SetExpressCheckout
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails
- DoExpressCheckoutPayment

SEC sets up the payment and returns a token.  Then you redirect the user to PayPal.  They sign in and agree to continue, which sends them back to your site.

Once back within your site/application, you call GECD to obtain the buyer's shipping address. At this point you may need to add more money to the order for shipping, tax, handling fees, etc.  If so, you would present a final review page to the buyer.

Once that is confirmed you'd call DECP to finalize the order with that final amount.

So that's why the amount could indeed change between the start and finish of the checkout flow, and that amount will always be required in both SEC and DECP regardless of the transaction type.